# Does this psu have enough power for this graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

PSU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139049
GPU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125491
While looking over for the specs for the PSU, I noticed it only had 1 PCI-E power connector, while the graphics card takes two. Am I simply misreading this or do I need a different PSU?

Comment: The GPU requires 2 6+2 - pin connectors so the PSU wouldn't be able to support it. 430W also seems a bit on the low side but I have a tendency to go a bit overboard sometimes. What are the specs for the rest of your computer?

Comment: http://pcpartpicker.com/user/alanhenry/saved/PNFtt6 Here is a full list of my specs

Comment: I wouldn't go with anything below 620W in terms of power supplies if it were me. It gives a little bit of headroom for upgrades and overclocking if you feel inclined to do so. Newegg has a helpful [Wattage Calculator](http://images10.newegg.com/BizIntell/tool/psucalc/index.html) that I like to use as a reference when building rigs.

Comment: The build uses <400 watts, so 620W is tons of overhead.

Comment: I made the mistake of assuming Dan was correct even though that number looked pretty fishy. It's been a long day for me :P . You also want about 30% overhead if my memory serves me correct so a 500W PSU should be more than sufficient.

Comment: So you don't have any fans / lights / etc in your case? Wow... it's been a long time since I've seen that :) But that being said, those corsair bronze PSUs, they're not really the best build for maxing out power. If you're dead on on a <500W PSU (ignoring GigaByte's recommendation), at least take a Gold instead of a Bronze. You may also lose warranty on your GPU should you have any problems...

Comment: And by the way... it's not because you'd have a 500W PSU that it will consume more than the 430W. It only ALLOWS you to consume more in case you need it.

Comment: Fancy lights are so unnecessary and make it difficult to sleep at night! I'll take a nice fan controller with a set of HAF (the real term escapes me at the moment) fans any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R9 270 uses 150W of power. I don't know what other equipment you have in your computer, but it doesn't sound like you will have sufficient power. I recommend at least a 500W PSU for an otherwise standard PC build.

If you're not sure how much your computer consumes, try to virtually build the system on http://pcpartpicker.com (including all disks, fans, optical drives, CPU, RAM and everything else that consumes power). It will let you know if you have any problems with your build.

Comment: Does pcpartpicker check for availability of PSU connectors? pcpartpicker seems to not show any problems with my build.

Comment: @Natecat check that by hand it's not hard everything required is in The specifications of the hardware

Answer (score 1):

[On the Gigabyte page they state that that GPU](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4840) requires a 500W PSU with two 6-pin external power connectors. The PSU you link to is only 430W and only has one 6-pin external power connector.

Look for PSU with at least 500W and with two 6-pin external power connectors